# TypeScript: Function callback return type not checked

Tags: typescript, callback

A function `fn` accepts a callback `cb` which returns a value of type `Foo`. Why is the callback able to return arbitrary values in addition to what `Foo` specifies?

```js
type Foo = {
    x: string;
}

const fn = (cb: () => Foo): Foo => ({
    x: '',
    y: [], // throws error as expected
    z: {}, // throws error as expected
})

fn(() => ({
    x: '',
    y: [], // why does this not throw an error?
    z: {}, // why does this not throw an error?
}))
```